# R - calculate difference between all combinations of observations within groups

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I want to compare the effect of different fertilizer doses on multiple crop cultivars at various locations. My dataset is similar to the one generated below:

```
locs <- rep(c("loc1","loc2","loc3"), length.out=180)
cults <- rep(c("cult1","cult2","cult3","cult4","cult5"), length.out=180)
doses <- rep(c("no_fert","40kg","50kg","60kg"), length.out=180)
set.seed(123); yld <- runif(3*length(unique(locs))*length(unique(cults))*length(unique(doses)), min=3, max=15)

dat <- data.frame(location=locs,
                  cultivar=cults,
                  fert_dose=doses,
                  yield=yld)
```

Note there are three repetitions of each fertilizer dosage (but there are more in my actual dataset).

The first thing I need to do is to calculate the average for the three repetitions of each location-cultivar-fertilizer combination.

I can do it - in a probably not so efficient way - like this:

```
d1 <- d2 <- d3 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(unique(locs))){
  for (j in 1:length(unique(cults))){
    for (k in 1:length(unique(doses))){
      d1[[k]] <- data.frame(location=locs[i],
                            cultivar=cults[j],
                            fert_dose=doses[k],
                            mean_yield=mean(dat[dat$location==locs[i]&dat$cultivar==cults[j]&dat$fert_dose==doses[k],]$yield))
    }
    d2[[j]] <- do.call(rbind,d1)
  }
  d3[[i]] <- do.call(rbind,d2)
}

(mean_dat <- do.call(rbind, d3))
```

Next, what I need to do is: for each location, find the yield difference among all combinations of cultivar and fertilizer doses.

For example, considering only `loc1` and `cult1`, the expected result would be:

```
res <- "
location cultivar dose dose_mean other_cultivar other_dose other_mean diff
loc1 cult1 no_fert 9.402345 cult1 40kg 9.251377 0.150968
loc1 cult1 no_fert 9.402345 cult1 50kg 10.764692 -1.362347
loc1 cult1 no_fert 9.402345 cult1 60kg 10.119129 -0.716784

loc1 cult1 40kg 9.251377 cult1 no_fert 9.402345 -0.150968
loc1 cult1 40kg 9.251377 cult1 50kg 10.764692 -1.513315
loc1 cult1 40kg 9.251377 cult1 60kg 10.119129 -0.867752

loc1 cult1 50kg 10.764692 cult1 no_fert 9.402345 1.362347
loc1 cult1 50kg 10.764692 cult1 40kg 9.251377 1.513315
loc1 cult1 50kg 10.764692 cult1 60kg 10.119129 0.645563

loc1 cult1 60kg 10.119129 cult1 no_fert 9.402345 0.716784
loc1 cult1 60kg 10.119129 cult1 40kg 9.251377 0.867752
loc1 cult1 60kg 10.119129 cult1 50kg 10.764692 -0.645563
"
(res <- read.table(textConnection(res), sep=" ", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F))
```

In this table, I am repeating the yield values for each dose obtained in the previous step (`mean_dat` table) and calculating a simple the difference between them. The resulting table would continue this analysis, including the other cultivars in the `other_cultivar` column.

I reckon the expected table does not look very good, but it will be used to feed an interactive dashboard, and this is the format it requires, so I don't think I have much choice here.

Is there any programmatic way to achieve these two results in just one step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(location, cultivar, dose = fert_dose) %>%
  summarize(dose_mean = mean(yield), .groups = "drop") %>%
  full_join(., ., by = "location", suffix = c("", "_other")) %>%
  filter(cultivar != cultivar_other | dose != dose_other) %>%
  mutate(diff = dose_mean - dose_mean_other)
# # A tibble: 1,140 x 8
#    location cultivar dose  dose_mean cultivar_other dose_other dose_mean_other     diff
#    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <dbl> <chr>          <chr>                <dbl>    <dbl>
#  1 loc1     cult1    40kg       9.25 cult1          50kg                 10.8  -1.51   
#  2 loc1     cult1    40kg       9.25 cult1          60kg                 10.1  -0.868  
#  3 loc1     cult1    40kg       9.25 cult1          no_fert               9.40 -0.151  
#  4 loc1     cult1    40kg       9.25 cult2          40kg                 10.1  -0.830  
#  5 loc1     cult1    40kg       9.25 cult2          50kg                  8.97  0.282  
#  6 loc1     cult1    40kg       9.25 cult2          60kg                  6.71  2.54   
#  7 loc1     cult1    40kg       9.25 cult2          no_fert              11.5  -2.20   
#  8 loc1     cult1    40kg       9.25 cult3          40kg                 11.9  -2.70   
#  9 loc1     cult1    40kg       9.25 cult3          50kg                  9.21  0.0421 
# 10 loc1     cult1    40kg       9.25 cult3          60kg                  9.26 -0.00416
# # ... with 1,130 more rows
```

Note that this is doing an outer join on `cultivar` and `dose`. We started with 180 rows and ended with 1140, this will grow geometrically.

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)[, .(dose_mean = mean(yield)), by = .(location, cultivar, dose = fert_dose)]
merge(DT, DT, by = "location", all = TRUE, suffix = c("", "_other"), allow.cartesian = TRUE
  )[(cultivar != cultivar_other | dose != dose_other),
  ][, diff := dose_mean - dose_mean_other][]
#       location cultivar    dose dose_mean cultivar_other dose_other dose_mean_other         diff
#         <char>   <char>  <char>     <num>         <char>     <char>           <num>        <num>
#    1:     loc1    cult1 no_fert  9.402345          cult4       60kg        8.508675  0.893670057
#    2:     loc1    cult1 no_fert  9.402345          cult2       50kg        8.969489  0.432856209
#    3:     loc1    cult1 no_fert  9.402345          cult5       40kg        9.345814  0.056530679
#    4:     loc1    cult1 no_fert  9.402345          cult3    no_fert       11.243009 -1.840663741
#    5:     loc1    cult1 no_fert  9.402345          cult1       60kg       10.119129 -0.716784445
#    6:     loc1    cult1 no_fert  9.402345          cult4       50kg        9.638162 -0.235817407
#    7:     loc1    cult1 no_fert  9.402345          cult2       40kg       10.081336 -0.678991009
#    8:     loc1    cult1 no_fert  9.402345          cult5    no_fert        9.405199 -0.002854273
#    9:     loc1    cult1 no_fert  9.402345          cult3       60kg        9.255537  0.146807576
#   10:     loc1    cult1 no_fert  9.402345          cult1       50kg       10.764692 -1.362347580
#   ---                                                                                           
# 1131:     loc3    cult5    60kg  8.442893          cult5       40kg        7.217206  1.225686617
# 1132:     loc3    cult5    60kg  8.442893          cult3    no_fert        8.688523 -0.245630492
# 1133:     loc3    cult5    60kg  8.442893          cult1       60kg        7.221926  1.220966527
# 1134:     loc3    cult5    60kg  8.442893          cult4       50kg        7.918912  0.523980425
# 1135:     loc3    cult5    60kg  8.442893          cult2       40kg        7.405098  1.037794838
# 1136:     loc3    cult5    60kg  8.442893          cult5    no_fert        6.963170  1.479722527
# 1137:     loc3    cult5    60kg  8.442893          cult3       60kg        8.183201  0.259691148
# 1138:     loc3    cult5    60kg  8.442893          cult1       50kg        9.444416 -1.001523464
# 1139:     loc3    cult5    60kg  8.442893          cult4       40kg       10.264777 -1.821884187
# 1140:     loc3    cult5    60kg  8.442893          cult2    no_fert        7.196217  1.246675164
```

Note that doing this is `data.table` works well but does not really reduce the memory footprint of in-place calculations or speed usually attributed to `data.table`-based solutions.

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, you can do the following join:

```r
library(data.table)

locs <- rep(c("loc1","loc2","loc3"), length.out=180)
cults <- rep(c("cult1","cult2","cult3","cult4","cult5"), length.out=180)
doses <- rep(c("no_fert","40kg","50kg","60kg"), length.out=180)
set.seed(123); yld <- runif(3*length(unique(locs))*length(unique(cults))*length(unique(doses)), min=3, max=15)

dat <- data.frame(location=locs,
                  cultivar=cults,
                  fert_dose=doses,
                  yield=yld)


setDT(dat)

dat[dat, .(cultivar_1 = cultivar, 
           cultivar_2 = i.cultivar,
           fert_dose_1 = fert_dose,
           fert_dose_2 = i.fert_dose,
           yield_1 = yield,
           yield_2 = i.yield,
           diff = yield - i.yield), on = "location", by = .EACHI][
           !(cultivar_1 == cultivar_2 & fert_dose_1 == fert_dose_2)][
             order(location, cultivar_1,fert_dose_1, cultivar_2, fert_dose_2)]

#>        location cultivar_1 cultivar_2 fert_dose_1 fert_dose_2   yield_1
#>     1:     loc1      cult1      cult1        40kg        50kg  4.665673
#>     2:     loc1      cult1      cult1        40kg        50kg 13.684203
#>     3:     loc1      cult1      cult1        40kg        50kg  9.404255
#>     4:     loc1      cult1      cult1        40kg        50kg  4.665673
#>     5:     loc1      cult1      cult1        40kg        50kg 13.684203
#>    ---                                                                 
#> 10256:     loc3      cult5      cult5     no_fert        60kg  8.794829
#> 10257:     loc3      cult5      cult5     no_fert        60kg  7.265345
#> 10258:     loc3      cult5      cult5     no_fert        60kg  4.829337
#> 10259:     loc3      cult5      cult5     no_fert        60kg  8.794829
#> 10260:     loc3      cult5      cult5     no_fert        60kg  7.265345
#>          yield_2        diff
#>     1: 14.556291 -9.89061803
#>     2: 14.556291 -0.87208812
#>     3: 14.556291 -5.15203544
#>     4:  4.568348  0.09732446
#>     5:  4.568348  9.11585437
#>    ---                      
#> 10256:  7.854123  0.94070539
#> 10257:  7.854123 -0.58877881
#> 10258:  9.981001 -5.15166422
#> 10259:  9.981001 -1.18617243
#> 10260:  9.981001 -2.71565663
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A tidy dplyr solution with adding all values for each location to a new column, then filtering to remove the few identical combinations:

```r
library(tidyverse)

myfunc <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    add_column(other = list(.)) %>%
    unnest(other, names_sep = "_") %>%
    filter(!(cultivar == other_cultivar & fert_dose == other_fert_dose)) %>%
    mutate(diff = yield - other_yield)
}

datmeans <- dat %>%
  group_by(location, cultivar, fert_dose) %>%
  summarise(yield = mean(yield), .groups = "drop") %>%
  group_split(location) %>%
  map(myfunc) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution that avoids a larger join and subsequent filtering. It will be fast and memory-efficient.

```
dat_mean <- setDT(dat)[,.(mean_yield = mean(yield)), location:fert_dose][, doseIdx := match(fert_dose, unique(fert_dose))]

rbindlist(
  lapply(
    parse(
      text = c(
        ".(location, doseIdx > doseIdx)",
        ".(location, doseIdx < doseIdx)"
      )
    ),
    function(e) {
      dat_mean[
        dat_mean,
        .(
          location,
          cultivar1 = cultivar,
          fert_dose1 = fert_dose,
          yield1 = mean_yield,
          cultivar2 = i.cultivar,
          fert_dose2 = i.fert_dose,
          yield2 = i.mean_yield,
          diff = mean_yield - i.mean_yield
        ),
        on = eval(e)
      ]
    }
  )
)
#>      location cultivar1 fert_dose1    yield1 cultivar2 fert_dose2   yield2        diff
#>   1:     loc1     cult4       60kg  8.508675     cult1    no_fert 9.402345 -0.89367006
#>   2:     loc1     cult2       50kg  8.969489     cult1    no_fert 9.402345 -0.43285621
#>   3:     loc1     cult5       40kg  9.345814     cult1    no_fert 9.402345 -0.05653068
#>   4:     loc1     cult1       60kg 10.119129     cult1    no_fert 9.402345  0.71678444
#>   5:     loc1     cult4       50kg  9.638162     cult1    no_fert 9.402345  0.23581741
#>  ---                                                                                  
#> 926:     loc3     cult2       40kg  7.405098     cult5       60kg 8.442893 -1.03779484
#> 927:     loc3     cult5    no_fert  6.963170     cult5       60kg 8.442893 -1.47972253
#> 928:     loc3     cult1       50kg  9.444416     cult5       60kg 8.442893  1.00152346
#> 929:     loc3     cult4       40kg 10.264777     cult5       60kg 8.442893  1.82188419
#> 930:     loc3     cult2    no_fert  7.196217     cult5       60kg 8.442893 -1.24667516
```